# '| cut' is not recognized as an external or internal command

Tags: python-3.x, shell, pycharm, face-recognition, pipenv

I'm trying to cut the file names while recognizing faces with face_recognition in the Pycharm terminal like this:

```
>face_recognition ./face_recognition/traversy_media/img/known ./face_recognition/traversy_media/img/unknown | cut -d ',' -f2
```

Like shown in this video (6:00):
'Python Face Recognition Tutorial'
by: traversy media
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSTnwsZj2yc&t=126s

But when i run the code it tells me:

```
'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I guess that the problem is the '|' which separates the 'cut' from my code
but I don't know how else to do it.

Also when I don't use the '|' it tells me:

```
Usage: face_recognition [OPTIONS] KNOWN_PEOPLE_FOLDER IMAGE_TO_CHECK
Try "face_recognition --help" for help.

Error: no such option: -d
```

Or when i remove the '|' and the '-d':

```
Usage: face_recognition [OPTIONS] KNOWN_PEOPLE_FOLDER IMAGE_TO_CHECK
Try "face_recognition --help" for help.

Error: no such option: -f
```

Comment: 'face_recognition --help' doesn't help.

Comment: What OS are you running? `cut` is a Linux/Unix tool

Comment: I'm using Windows, do you know how to do it on windows?

Comment: Could it be that you don't have a `cut` command on your system? If you are on Windows, you could try to find it on the [Gnu tools for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), or you download the whole [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) environment, including Python, and use the Cygwin version of Python3. The latter is more work to setup, but you will end up with a reasonable environment to work under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

`cut` isn't available on Windows, but you have two potential solutions.

1. Try using Cygwin or Git for Windows
2. Write the equivalent code. I don't have access to a Windows machine to test, but you can try this

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %i in ("face_recognition ./face_recognition/traversy_media/img/known ./face_recognition/traversy_media/img/unknown") DO echo %i
```

Comment: You can also use GnuWin32 Coreutils which adds commands like `cut`